# kubectl alias and autocomplete not working for powershell

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, kubectl

Trying to get the [auto-complete](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/#optional-kubectl-configurations-and-plugins) feature of `kubectl` working with an alias of `k`, using `Windows PowerShell` and `PowerShell Core` on Windows Server 2022, but can't get it to work

tested with

```
echo 'Set-Alias -Name k -Value kubectl' >> $PROFILE
kubectl completion powershell >> $PROFILE
```

or even simply this to try to get it working in the same session, without worrying about saving it to the PowerShell profile

```
Set-Alias -Name k -Value kubectl
kubectl completion powershell | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
```

Results so far:

**Powershell 5.1**
Tab completion with `kubectl`: **OK**
Tab completion with `k`: **Fails**

**Powershell Core 7.3**
Tab completion with `kubectl`: **Fails**
Tab completion with `k`: **Fails**

The results above are tested with both `Windows Terminal` and `cmd`

Am I missing something obvious? (like I normally do)

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if the issue with kubectl auto-complete not working at all on PowerShell Core is related to the underlying Cobra library "requiring PowerShell 5.0 or above".    
`Users need PowerShell version 5.0 or above, which comes with Windows 10 and can be downloaded separately for Windows 7 or 8.1.`

https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/main/shell_completions.md#powershell-completions

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell completions by alias in cobra supported only from version 1.6.0. kubectl depends on cobra 1.6.0 since v1.26 version. So, you should use kubectl v1.26+ and [powershell 5.0+](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/main/shell_completions.md#powershell-completions)

I use it with powershell 7.3, kubectl v1.26.1  in windows 10
but it suggest variants only after typing first letter (it doesn't show select menu without typing any letter)

```
Set-Alias -Name k -Value kubectl
kubectl completion powershell | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName k -ScriptBlock $__kubectlCompleterBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

So go it working on PowerShell 5.1 with this, and assuming that Cobra only works on Powershell 5.x as per [this](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/main/shell_completions.md#powershell-completions), so given up on getting PowerShell Core working!

```
# Powershell 5.x
echo 'Set-Alias -Name k -Value kubectl' >> $PROFILE
echo 'Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName k -ScriptBlock $__kubectlCompleterBlock'  >> $PROFILE
kubectl completion powershell >> $PROFILE
# Reload the PowerShell profile
. $PROFILE
```